# changing wordpress Site Address (url) breaks site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have Wordpress installed within a directory called /wordpress/. In order to remove this from the URL's, I've changed the Wordpress setting Site Address (URL) in the Settings section of wp-admin. However, this breaks the site and causes all wordpress pages to return a 404 error. What's happening? Am I using the Site Address setting incorrectly?

```
Wordpress Address (URL): http://www.vapetropolis.ca/wordpress
Site Address (URL): http://www.vapetropolis.ca
```

Comment: You need to update 2 urls in database and modify permalinks/.htaccess in order for this to work, look at this http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: The actual wordpress files are located at: http://www.vapetropolis.ca/wordpress, but I want the URL to only show http://www.vapetropolis.ca. The site is pointed correctly at the wordpress files - I just want to remove /wordpress from the URLs.

Comment: @valen you mean like this ? http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: @Prix Just did this - it worked for wordpress, but now all magento links are broken. It's redirecting every link on the site to the wordpress subdirectory, so it will never find the magento pages.

Comment: @valen that is for wordpress only so yes obviously it will not work properly for other scripts. Is your magento on the root folder ? on a magento folder ?

Comment: @Prix - yes, Magento is in the root folder. Wordpress is in subdirectory.

Comment: then I am afraid this wont be possible due to how magento works they would conflict with each other, why dont u make a subdomain called blog.yourdomain.ca and use that for wordpress instead ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34301/discussion-between-valen-and-prix)

Comment: have you solved the problem ? I wrote some code to fix that which worked fine for me. For now it's quite ugly made and I'm wondering if there's anybody else who needs something like this and if it's worth to rewrite it and publish.

Comment: You sure that you don't have your Wordpress files in /var/www/html as well??